# Is there a way to insert a Text Box or a drawing programmatically in the Text Editor of Google Docs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I'm creating an add-on for Google Docs and I want to show some text near a text selection, the problem I'm facing right now is that I'm unable to find anything that could solve this problem.

Searching through the documentation of the API I've found there's a class called InlineDrawing but there's almost no reference on how that works.

What's the best way to do something like that?

Comment: Have you checked [this SO post (Modifying a drawing using Google Apps Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996422/modifying-a-drawing-using-google-apps-script)?

Comment: The documentation that guy posted there uses Java, Python and PHP, I use JavaScript so it has no use for me, and I can't find that same thing on JavaScript