# Linking a Google Slide (and Drawing) to a Google Doc using API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I need to add a Google Drawing to a Google Doc and I would like to know if that is possible using the API.

I have been able to modify the Drawing using the Slides API (see code below) but I am not able to link this Slide to the Google Doc.

```
function logSlidesAndElements() {
    var presentationId = 'id_id_id_id_id_...';
    var presentation = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId);
    var slides = presentation.slides;

    // Log the elements in the slide
    for (var i = 0; i < slides[0].pageElements.length; i++) {
        if (slides[1].pageElements[i]['shape']['shapeType'] == 'TEXT_BOX') {
            Logger.log(i);
            Logger.log(slides[1].pageElements[i]['objectId']);
            Logger.log(slides[1].pageElements[i]['shape']['text']['textElements'][1]['textRun']['content']);
        }
    }

    // Modify one of the elements
    var requests = [{
        updateShapeProperties: {
            objectId: slides[1].pageElements[8]['objectId'],
            fields: 'shapeBackgroundFill.solidFill.color',
            shapeProperties: {
                shapeBackgroundFill: {
                    solidFill: {
                        color: green_application_map
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }];

    var batchUpdateResponse = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({
        requests: requests
    }, presentationId);

}
```

I see there is a list of inlineObjects inside the document body[1], and if I add a linked slide manually (copy and paste from google slides to google doc) to the google Doc and print the document object with code below

```
var document = Docs.Documents.get(doc_id);
var docElements = document;
console.log(docElements);
```

What I see is (just the relevant part):

```
kix.l46ge8x1m={ 
      ...
      inlineObjectProperties={ 
            linkedContentReference={ 

            },
            imageProperties={ 
               cropProperties={ 

               },
               contentUri=https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/really_long_id_to_the_generated_image_from_the_slide
            }

      ...
      },
      objectId=kix.l46ge8x1m
   }
```

There is a link to an image generated from the drawing but I don't see anything related to the linked Slide.

I would expect to see something inside the *linkedContentReference* but is empty so I am not sure if is possible to link the generated Slide (and Drawing) to the Doc.

[1] https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that although the pasted Slide on the Google Document is linked to the original Slides, when the Document is retrieved with Docs API, the link from Slides is not included. And also, in the current stage, it seems that the slide cannot be inserted with Docs API. Docs API is growing now. So this might be modified in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, I will try to generate an image from the Drawing and insert it to the Doc